# I am using \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession in my block but it is not working without cacheable false

Tags: magento2

If we need to get current customer session in a block, cacheable must be set to false in the `layout xml`. I am using `\Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession` in my block but it is not working without cacheable false. Can someone tell me a recommended way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Session is cached in blocks by default. However you can use a cacheable = false to use a Session in block but is not recommended.

I recommend to use a Registry to store/get information in blocks. If you need specific info from Session you can set this info in a Registry from Controller of your Block.

Here is some info: https://meetanshi.com/blog/use-registry-in-magento-2/

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this? It Might be help you.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;


class Form extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {

        var_dump($this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId());
        exit();
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, the part of `return parent::_prepareLayout();` would not be executed, because it is being blocked by `exit()`